# Books about constructivist approach for proof

Tags: book-recommendation, constructive-mathematics

I'm interested about the constructivist approach to math, and how the proof works in thoose framework.

What are good introductory books I can read? I'm interested in online sources

Answer (score 2):

Constructivism in Mathematics, Vol 1 (Volume 121) (Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics, Volume 121).